# byte[] to bool[] to use as flags and viceversa

Tags: c#, boolean, arrays, bit, bitarray

Ok, so i have a byte[] that i get using
`File.ReadAllBytes(filename);`
My problem is that my program needs to treat the data from the file as an array of bools.
I have searched but i didn't manage to find a way to get a correct and efficient conversion.
An example would be:

```
{ 00101011, 10111010 } ->
            { false, false, true, false, true, false, false, true, true,
              false, true, true, true, false, true, false }
```

I will also be needing to reverse the procedure.

Most Solutions i came across involved getting one boolean out of each byte. i.e, the resulting array of `bool[]` had the same length as the `byte[]` array, i don't seem to understand how this is possible, how do 8 bits result in only one boolean value?
In my case i need to have a resulting array as: `bool[bytes.Length * 8].`

Thanks alot, any help is highly appreciated.

Implementing one of the solutions i tryed to get this to work but it is somehow wrong because the resulting file, which is a copy of the file i read gets damaged:

```
public static bool[] boolsFromFile(string filename)
    {
        List<bool> b = new List<bool>();
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
        using (BinaryReader read = new BinaryReader(fileStream))
        {
            while (fileStream.Position != fileStream.Length)
                b.Add(read.ReadBoolean());
        }
        return b.ToArray();
    }

    public static void boolsToFile(string filename, bool[] bools)
    {
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
        using (BinaryWriter write = new BinaryWriter(fileStream))
        {
            foreach (bool b in bools)
                write.Write(b);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try using [bitwise operations](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_bitwise_operators.htm).

Comment: How is the file made in the first place. If the file is made with a BinaryWriter it would be obvious to read the file with BinaryReader.

Comment: @Esben suggesting to read the file the same way as it's written is a good one, however the BinaryWriter [writes bools as bytes as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057747/write-one-single-bit-to-binary-file-using-binarywriter).

Comment: @CodeCaster Yest i tried this and i think it is my best chance.
I Managed to read a file and rewrite a new copy, the new file i write has exactly the same size but is somehow damaged. Could i be missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[A .NET bool "wastes" seven bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335841/what-is-the-binary-representation-of-a-boolean-value-in-c-sharp). So there is no direct way to go from a byte to eight booleans.

You could use the [BitArray class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray(v=vs.110).aspx), see [Converting C# byte to BitArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11204666/converting-c-sharp-byte-to-bitarray).

So something like this:

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
var bitArray = new BitArray(bytes);
bool ninthBit = bitArray[8];
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy with Linq

```
            byte[] input = new byte[] { 0x2b, 0xba };
            Boolean[][] results = input.Select(x => Enumerable.Repeat(x,8).Select((y, i) => ((y >> (7 - i)) & 1) == 0 ? false : true).ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Comment: I would say it might be easy, but it certainly isn't readable. He's looking for a BitMask.@CodeCaster's solution seems more fitting and unproportionately more readable.

Comment: Don't guess what the person wants in this case.  If he is looking for a bit mask  then there is absolutely no reason to do any conversion.  A byte is a mask.

Comment: Right, but why go through a complicated linq when there's something a lot more simple to work with?

Comment: I can't answer your question only the person who wrote the question can.  He said he needed an array of Boolean so I gave him one.